# Error while installing soca gem in couchdb docker image

Tags: ruby, docker, rubygems

i am trying to run the Following Docker File but when it trys to Install the gem "soca" it always fails with following error

Error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing soca:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby2.1 extconf.rb
checking for re.h... no
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling parser.c
In file included from /usr/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby.h:33:0,
                 from parser.h:4,
                 from parser.rl:1:
parser.rl: In function 'JSON_parse_object':
/usr/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:437:18: error: expected '(' before '!' token
 #define RTEST(v) !(((VALUE)(v) & ~Qnil) == 0)
                  ^
parser.rl:165:20: note: in expansion of macro 'RTEST'
                 VALUE klass = rb_funcall(mJSON, i_deep_const_get, 1, klassname);
                    ^
/usr/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:437:18: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
 #define RTEST(v) !(((VALUE)(v) & ~Qnil) == 0)
                  ^
parser.rl:165:20: note: in expansion of macro 'RTEST'
                 VALUE klass = rb_funcall(mJSON, i_deep_const_get, 1, klassname);
                    ^
parser.rl:165:68: error: expected ';' before '{' token
                 VALUE klass = rb_funcall(mJSON, i_deep_const_get, 1, klassname);
                                                                    ^
Makefile:224: recipe for target 'parser.o' failed
make: *** [parser.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/json-1.4.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/json-1.4.6/gem_make.out
```

This is the Docker File i am running
Which uses couchdb image and
then Installs hopefully everthing it needs to run ruby gems

```
FROM couchdb:1

# custom setup RUN apt-get update RUN apt-get --assume-yes install ruby RUN apt-get --assume-yes install ruby-dev RUN apt-get
--assume-yes install rubygems RUN apt-get --assume-yes install build-essential bison openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libxml2-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool RUN gem install soca
-v 0.3.0

COPY local.ini /usr/local/etc/couchdb/

EXPOSE 5984
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a problem with a Ruby gem which uses native extensions and it looks in particular like the problem is with the JSON gem: https://rubygems.org/gems/json/versions/1.4.6

This may have to do with the version of Ruby you have.

You can try to install the gem by itself to see what the error is:

```
gem install json -v 1.4.6
```

This is how I have been able to get a more informative error message and been able to figure out what native libraries are missing.